# How to run commands on a remote host with an existing user on that machine

Tags: bash, shell, ssh-keys

I am writing a shell scripts that requires to run commands on multiple remote host based on condition it satisfies. how can i run the commands on the remote host using its key pair and assign the output of those commands to a variable on the primary host.

I tried using

```
sshpass -f keypair hostname 'command' | 'commands'
```

but this command executed on the host itself.

Comment: On the remote host the commands can be executed only by a specific user not as root.

Comment: You're not executing `ssh hostname`

Answer (score 0):

Use command substitution to assign the output of a command to a variable. You also need to run the `ssh` command and specify the remote username.

```
variable=$(sshpass -f keypair ssh username@hostname 'command')
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Add host public keys (~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)to remote user authenticated keys (~/.ssh/authorized_keys)

You will append the content of the public key to the authorized_keys

2) If you don't have this key you may generate it

```
 ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

3) after that you can

```
ssh <REMOTE USER NAME>@RemoteHOST  <command>
```

As example

```
ssh mebada@123.44.2.12 ls
```

4) If you have list of commands you may scp shell file and execute it from there ( without password too ) and it will override the remote

```
scp /path/to/shell.file user@host:/path/to/remote
ssh user@host chmod u+x /path/to/remote/shell.file
ssh user@host /path/to/remote/shell.file
```